# Xpath cannot check passing attribute using namespace

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

Using this xpath exercise code:

```
<datasource formatted-name='Activity' inline='true' source-platform='win' version='18.1' xmlns:user='http://www.tableausoftware.com/xml/user'>
  <column datatype='integer' name='[Number of Records]' role='measure' type='quantitative' user:auto-column='numrec'>
    <calculation class='tableau' formula='1' />
  </column>
</datasource>
```

I want to extract `@name`, but only if the attribute `user:auto-column` exists.

All I could come up with is:

1. `//column[@auto-column]/@name`
2. `//column[@user:auto-column]/@name`
3. `//column[@auto-column=user:column[@auto-column]]/@name`

The 1st one worked in only one of xpath testers I found online, the rest of them didn't work at all.

I have looked everywhere I could (read questions here on stackoverflow, checked out tutorials/documentation/questions on w3schools, microsoft, ibm, xpath testers, tutorials and cheetsheets) and tried to solve for hours.

How can I select the `@name` of `column` elements that have `@user:auto-column`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the attribute `@user:auto-column` is bound to a namespace. The `user` prefix is declared on the element above: `xmlns:user='http://www.tableausoftware.com/xml/user'`.

The first XPath shouldn't have worked, unless the XPath tester you were using simply ignored all namespaces and processed namespace-unaware.

The second XPath in your list is what you would want to use, in order to address that namespace-qualified attribute:

```
//column[@user:auto-column]/@name
```

However, you need to ensure that the namespace for the `user` prefix is declared and available in the context of whatever you are using to execute the XPath.

Otherwise, you would want to look for a namespace agnostic means of matching and filtering just on the `local-name()`. For instance:

```
//column[@*[local-name() = 'auto-column']]/@name
```

Now, because it is only filtering by the `local-name()` of the attribute, you run the risk of matching elements that have a similar attribute name that is bound to a totally different namespace, not the tableau namespace. That is probably unlikely, but just for awareness.

Comment: Thank you very very much! People like you make this world a better place!

Comment: @RaffaMusicman In case this resolved your problem please accept the answer